# Should I care about Low Testosterone?

Tags: health, hormones

My doctor wants to start some testosterone treatments on me because he says my levels are too low (they are 231 ng/dL and he said it should be between 348 to 1197). The question I have is, given that I don't have a girlfriend/wife, have never been on a date and am still a virgin (age 38 virgins, yes we exist), is there really any need for me to worry about my testosterone level?  It seems everywhere I look on google it is all about sex and sex drive. As someone that has no need for sex or a sex drive (see no wife nor girlfriend), is there anything else I would even care about? Do I really need to up my testosterone?

Comment: Since your doctor recommends it you should probably listen. I don't always agree with everything they say, but they are rarely wrong.

Comment: Testosterone is vital to normal functioning, and you are too young to be going through andropause. Cardiovascular problems are at the top of the list with longstanding testo deficiency.

Comment: This is a very personal question, and medical advise as well. Both of these are off topic for the site, unfortunately.

Comment: i strongly recommend you listen to this entire podcast, especially the part about the man who had NONE.http://www.thisamericanlife.org/radio-archives/episode/220/testosterone

Comment: Before accepting any treatment with artificial testosterone, I would try by all means to rise my natural levels for a while (basically getting more sleep, doing strength training, and eating some more saturated fats). Try everything at your disposal before starting a testosterone treatment, since they are for life. Once you start receiving exogenous testosterone, your balls will become lazy very quickly an then they will produce even less than before, making you dependent from the exogenous source. Also, go and see another doctor, look for a second opinion.

Comment: @DarkoSarovic Thanks for the info, I wish you put this as an answer as I would accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, only your doctor can know if your levels are actually low enough to cause these symptoms, so you should ask them. I'm only including the rest of this answer to let you know it's worth asking.

As it relates to fitness, low levels of testosterone can lead to reduced muscle and bone mass [[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Androgen_deficiency#Signs_and_symptoms)]. Low muscle mass (and presumably reduced muscular gain) is obviously bad if you're interested in getting stronger or bigger. Reduced bone mass is bad for just about any kind of exercising that involves impacts or heavy loads, like running or lifting, because it increases your chance of injury.